# ASP.NET MVC - Access a controller property in an ActionFilter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, action-filter

I'm using Unity to instantiate a new class into the controller constructor and save the injected class in a property inside the controller. Then I want to use an ActionFilter to see if the injected class has some properties that I validate inside it's constructor. So is there a way to use an ActionFilter to validade the properties of the injected class?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 47):

Something like this?:

```
public class ValidateActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var yourController = filterContext.Controller as YourController;

        if (yourController == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("It is not YourController !!!");
        }

        // It is YourController - validate here
        var yourProperty = yourController.YourProperty;

        // UPDATED ***************************
        // or test whether controller has property

        var property = filterContext.Controller.GetType().GetProperty("YourProperty");

        if(property == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("There is no YourProperty !!!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks skaffman. The thing is the filter will be in every controller but not all of them will have the property defined. So I have to look to see if it exists in the current controller and then check the value if it does :)...

Comment: The easiest way to do this would be to make an IContainsYourProperty interface (with a single YourProperty property) and have controllers which expose this property implement the interface, then the filter can check for the existence of this interface on the controller.  Otherwise, use Reflection to check for the property, but this is probably overkill.

Comment: That was what I ended up doing. Thanks Levi :)