# return generic action post method mvc in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm interested in Redirect of reference action post
And I want it to be similar to the generic

```
        ActionResult action = new DashboardController().Index(3);
        return action;
```

i wants code like this

> Because I redirect to a page using the POST
>   I can't using this

```
return RedirectToAction(actionName, controllerName);
```

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1343182/5996253)

```
        public ActionResult generic(string Controller,string Action)
        {
            Assembly asm = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MvcApplication));

            var controlleractionlist = asm.GetTypes()
                    .Where(type => typeof(Controller).IsAssignableFrom(type));

            return typeof(typeof(controlleractionlist).GetProperty(Controller))
           .GetProperty(Action);
            }
```

Links can help Perhaps the answer
[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21583278/getting-all-controllers-and-actions-names-in-c-sharp)
[link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1171484/5996253)

I apologize in advance for my English