# pass value returned from a method to action filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, service, action-filter

I have `_serviceOne` injected into my controller that has a method which returns an `int` value. I'm trying to pass this value into my custom action filter.

This isn't working and I am getting the error: `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'NameController._serviceOne'` where I try to set the `Number = _serviceOne.GetIntNumber`.

I am aware that I can access a value if it is inside the controller (eg: controller parameter, ViewBag, ViewData, a variable in the controller), but I want to pass the value to the `CustomActionFilter` filter's `Number` property.

The filter and service method work the way I want it to, but it won't let me pass the value from `_serviceOne.GetIntNumber` into the filter. Why is this not working, and how could I make it work?

NameController.cs:

```
public class NameController : Controller
{
    private readonly ServiceOne _serviceOne;

    public NameController(ServiceOne serviceOne)
    {
        _serviceOne = serviceOne;
    }

    [CustomActionFilter(Name = "CorrectName", Number = _serviceOne.GetIntNumber)] //does not work
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

CustomActionFilter.cs:

```
public class CustomActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (Name == "CorrectName" && Number == 1) {
            RouteValueDictionary routeDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary { { "action", "SomeAction" }, { "controller", "NameController" } };
            context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(routeDictionary);
        }

        base.OnActionExecuted(context);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes are created at compile time so it's not possible to pass them run-time values in the constructor.

Instead, you can access `NameController`'s instance of the service, like this:

```
public class NameController : Controller
{
    private readonly ServiceOne _serviceOne;

    public ServiceOne ServiceOne => _serviceOne;

    public NameController(ServiceOne serviceOne)
    {
        _serviceOne = serviceOne;
    }
}

public class CustomActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var controller = context.Controller as NameController;
        var service = controller.ServiceOne;
        //Use the service here
    }
}
```

See also [Access a controller's property from an action filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171359/asp-net-mvc-access-a-controller-property-in-an-actionfilter)

Comment: Cool! This could be expanded to be more testable with a custom _IControllerService_ interface that includes an _IService_ property.  From there you could access any implemented _IService_ properties within the filter.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you explain what _public ServiceOne ServiceOne => _serviceOne;_ does? I can't seem to figure out the _=>_ part and the double class names.

Comment: It's an [expression-bodied](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members) property that exposes `_serviceOne` as public. This is necessary because your ActionFilter is a different class from `NameController` and can't access its private fields. You could also just make the field public or replace it entirely with a public property.